# AngularJS ui-router - Generated <href="">returns current url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs and have been scouring for an answer to this problem but to no luck I can't find one.I know that angular (1.x) is older but I still wanted to learn this anyway.

Moving on, I'm trying to dynamically generate links based on a **$scope.menu_item** object inside a controller of my module. For example if

```
$scope.menu_items = ['Home','Profile','Settings']
```

the values in the array correspond to child states of parent state User and is  configured using **$stateProvider.state()**

```
$stateProvider
.state('user'{
 url:'/user',
 abstract:true, 
 templateUrl:'someTemplateThatSeemsToWork',
 controller:'MenuCtrl'})
 
//these are the child states
.state('user.Home',{
 url:'/home',
 template:'<p>Home</p>' (this is loaded in the template of its parent)
})
.state('user.Profile',{
 url:'/profile',
 template:'<p>Profile</p>'
})
.state('user.Settings',{
 url:'/settings',
 template:'<p>Settings</p>'
 })
```

then this in the template using ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="menu_item in menu_items">
<a ui-state="user.{{menu_item}}">{{menu_item}}</a>
</li>
```

As expected, it renders the view properly, the values from **$scope.menu_items** are properly made into links **but** the href="" attribute of the  tag is equal to the current url.

The default state is 'user.Home' and as such **/user** redirects to **/user/home
(localhost:[port]/user/home)**

```
<a ui-state="user.Home" class="ng-binding" href="/user/home">Home</a>
...
<a ui-state="user.Profile" class="ng-binding" href="/user/home">Profile</a>
...
<a ui-state="user.Settings" class="ng-binding" href="/user/home">Settings</a>
```

Here we see that all of the generated  tags have the href value set to the current url (localhost:[port]/user/profile will make it into href="/user/profile")

So is there anything that I'm forgetting to do? From my understanding, it should work when I use ui-state since it can handle $scope properties.

Some additional notes:

1.) Manually typing the specified state url in the address bar works just fine and renders the correct template

2.) I am using Express to handle the server-side

3.) I set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

## Temporary Work-around

For the people who might stumble upon this question, I temporarily used a work-around solution and just removed **ui-sref=""** or **ui-state=""** and just used

```
ng-href={{state.url}}
```

with

```
ng-repeat= "state in states"
```

where

```
states = [{name="stateName", url="/relativeToRootUrl"},{..more States}]
```

I'd still appreciate a solution for this using ui-sref since it utilized ui-router more.

Comment: change to `#/user/home`

Comment: Sorry but can I ask, where specifically? The three <a> tags above are from the rendered html that I was able to view using 'Inspect Element' in my browser. I can't change them and they should automatically be equal to the url in my declared states.